# Output JAXB annotated bean property and suppress element tag

Tags: java, jaxb

I currently have the following two POJO classes.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User {
    @XmlElement
    private String firstName;
    @XmlElement
    private String lastName;
    @XmlElement
    private String email;

    /* snipped getters, setters, and constructors. */
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "testobj")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TestObj {
    @XmlElement(name="data")
    private String someData;
    @XmlElement
    private User user;

    /* snipped getters, setters, and constructors. */
}
```

**Current Output**

```
<testObj>
    <name>testObj</name>
    <user>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Doe</lastName>
        <email>john@doe.org</email>
    </user>
</testObj>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<testObj>
    <data>some data</data>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
    <email>john@doe.org</email>
</testObj>
```

Is there any way I can achieve the desired output?
The rationale for nesting the user object is that there are type heirarchies like so:

```
User
  |-> Customer
        |-> SpecialCustomer

DetailedUser
  |-> DetailedCustomer
        |-> DetailedSpecialCustomer
```

These six types are used specifically for holding data that will be outputted as the result of API calls. They have no logic in them. There is another more complex set of types that is used internally by the application, and a set of factories to convert the internal app types to the api output types. 
The API output types are serialized to XML and JSON using JAXB and Jackson.
In order to avoid duplicated code, I want to use composition to embed the simple User|Customer|SpecialCustomer in the complex type like so:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DetailedUser {
    @Xml[...?]
    private User user;
    @XmlElement
    private String otherProperty;
    @XmlElement
    private String extraStuff;

    /* snipped getters, setters, and constructors. */
}
```

When the DetailedUser is outputted through JAXB, it should look like so:

```
<user>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
    <email>john@doe.org</email>
    <otherProperty>something</otherProperty>
    <extraStuff></extraStuff>
</user>
```

The object tree will be outputted in the appropriate format via Spring MVC using content negotiation.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use MOXy's `@XmlPath(".")` extension:

**TestObj**

```
package forum10844319;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name = "testobj")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TestObj {
    @XmlElement(name="data")
    private String someData;
    @XmlPath(".")
    private User user;

    /* snipped getters, setters, and constructors. */
}
```

**User**

```
package forum10844319;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User {
    @XmlElement
    private String firstName;
    @XmlElement
    private String lastName;
    @XmlElement
    private String email;

    /* snipped getters, setters, and constructors. */
}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum10844319;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestObj.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum10844319/input.xml");
        TestObj testObj = (TestObj) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(testObj, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<testobj>
    <data>some data</data>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
    <email>john@doe.org</email>
</testobj>
```

Comment: That looks perfect. The only issue is Spring MVC integration. Are there any examples of setting up Spring MVC with MOXy for JSON and XML? I have had a look at how it is done for JAXB, but Spring only seems to have a Jackson MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter, whereas for XML it has the MarshallingMessageConverter which can be used with any XML marshaller.